# Webpack2 equivalent of html script tags?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack-2

I have downloaded an npm module which recommends adding:

```
<link href="node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.js"></script>
```

To my index.html file.

Is there a way that I can require the same references with Webpack 2 from an angular2 component?

e.g.

```
import 'ng2-toastr.min.js'
```

in the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advice given in the instructions is strange. You should not have to ever include the `<script>` tag, since you are using webpack, the script will load automatically for you as part of your webpack bundle.

As for the `css`, you can use webpack for that as well. First you will need to install the appropriate loaders to be able to load the `css` file and to apply the styles to the dom:

```
npm install --save style-loader raw-loader
```

Then somewhere in your typescript files you can do:

```
import 'style!raw!../node_modules/ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr.css'
```

(note that the relative path to your `../node_modules` might differ depending on the level of nesting in your application.

The  `style!` and `raw!` prefixes are instructions for webpack to process the given script through *"loaeers"*.

The `raw` loader will just read in the css file as is without trying to do any further processing (you can use the `css!` loader if you need to do additioanl things like `@import` from the `.css` file, but in this case that's not necessary, so the easiest is the raw loader.

The `style` loader takes the css loaded by the `raw` loader and programatically applies it to the current page dom. It does not actually create a `<style>` tag with a `src="url...."`, but it achieves the important part which is to make sure the styles in the loaded css are loaded on the page.

If you need to do this often, you can always add the loader config to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
     {test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader'},
     {test: /\.css$/, loader:'style!raw'}
  ] 
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
import '../node_modules/ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr.css'
```